# C3 draggable not working in line chart

Tags: charts, draggable, c3.js

I recently started using c3 and loving it so far. I have a basic line chart and want to have the points draggable. So according to the docs, I added `selection: { draggable: true }` in my data as follows:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart-' + this.toolId,
            data: {
                columns: [column1, column2],
                selection: { draggable: true }
            }
        });
```

but I can not drag the points. I also tried setting the option in one of the examples on c3 website. It's not working there as well. Am I missing something here? Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

The functionality I want is to be able to drag the data points and the line adjusts itself accordingly. For example, http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434

Comment: Unfortunately, in C3, draggable doesn't mean data points can be moved, but that an area on screen can be selected via mouse-drag and the points within it selected. Possibly would be better renamed as brushable? http://jsfiddle.net/xkh38wz8/

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. Is there any way in C3 to achieve the point drag feature?

Comment: Not by configuration. Obviously as the bl.ocks example shows it could be done by writing some extra d3 on top, but even here using C3 actually complicates things, as C3 hides away the scale used for the axis in an internal object, which is what you'd need to map y-axis drag values back to a new data value

Comment: I see. Would you say that I am better off with using D3 if I need more control on my visualizations instead of using a library such as C3?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you're setting is for selection only. And the documentation is also telling that:
`Enable TO SELECT data points by dragging.` So after enabling this feature, the point wouldn't be draggable as in your example but they'll be just selectable by dragging.

But recently I found a way to make it draggable: [look at JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hakobpogh/wvmz6bua/)

In the solution, only the ordinates are changed but the solution for abscises can be done in the same way.